# Calling Persistent<Function> callback segfaults in AfterWork

Tags: node.js, v8

The below code works in OS X, but when I compile & run it in Ubuntu, I get a segfault when calling the `baton->callback` function. It seems that the `Persistent<Function>` doesn't persist past the initial `Aysnc::Start` method.

If this is the case, **why does it work on OS X**? 
**What can I do to make it work cross-platform**?

**If I'm doing it wrong**, what do I need to do in order to make my `callback` callable from `AfterWork`?

```
// Async.h

#include <v8.h>
#include <node.h>
#include <string>

using namespace node;
using namespace v8;

class Async : public ObjectWrap {
  public:
    static Persistent<Function> constructor_template;
    static void Initialize(Handle<v8::Object> target);

  protected:
    Async() {}
    ~Async() {}

    static Handle<Value> Start(const Arguments& args);
    static void Work(uv_work_t* req);
    static void AfterWork(uv_work_t* req);
  private:

    struct Baton {
      uv_work_t request;
      Persistent<Function> callback;
    };
};

// Async.cc
Handle<Value> Async::Start(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  if(args.Length() == 0 || !args[0]->IsFunction()) {
    return ThrowException(Exception::Error(String::New("Callback is required and must be a Function.")));
  }

  Baton *baton = new Baton();
  baton->request.data = baton;
  baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));

  uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &baton->request, Work, (uv_after_work_cb)AfterWork);

  return Undefined();
}

void Async::Work(uv_work_t *req) {
  printf("Work\n");
}

void Async::AfterWork(uv_work_t *req) {
  printf("AfterWork\n");
  HandleScope scope;

  Baton *baton = static_cast<Baton *>(req->data);
  delete req;

    Local<Value> argv[1] = {
      Local<Value>::New(Null());
    };

    TryCatch try_catch;
    // Segfault occurs here
    baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, argv);
    if (try_catch.HasCaught()) {
      node::FatalException(try_catch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `libuv`, but given your definition of `Baton`, and assuming that the `uv_work_t*` passed into `AfterWork()` is the same as the one passed into `uv_queue_work()`, your `delete req` statement actually deletes your `Baton` structure, from which you then attempt to read the `callback` field. I'd try removing `delete req` and adding `delete baton` at the very end of `AfterWork()`.